# "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:" - Guava dependency problem?

Tags: java, dependencies, guava

I was so happy to fix one bug in my program with Your help today and since then... I'm working on another one for several... hours. So I get an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
```

I've read on the Internet it has something to do with Guava version (I'm using Maven), but I've tried several versions and still having the same issue. Currently, my POM file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>StorwareTest1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm starting to loose my faith...

Answer (score 0):

For future generations ;)
I solved this problem by updating my POM with this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Seems that I had the old version of guava. I was checking many versions, and that one solved my issue.